# Can't boot Ubuntu after reinsntallation, no available boot options for Ubuntu in the BIOS either

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I previously had Ubuntu, but I had to delete it for some reason, so my PC just had Windows at the moment. Then for college work I had to install Ubuntu again. I installed Ubuntu again using the same procedure that I followed during the previous installation. I heard that it's a safer option to dismount the hard drive containing Windows before installing Ubuntu so I did just that, and I installed Ubuntu on a separate hard drive.

- Made a primary partition with ext4 filesystem.
- Created a swap area of around 8GB as my RAM is 8GB too.
- And during the previous (working) Ubuntu installation, it asked me to make an EFI system partition which was later deleted, so this time I made it beforehand.

After installing Ubuntu, the BIOS doesn't show me any boot options for Ubuntu like it did previously. If I don't enter the BIOS and let the system boot on its own, it shows `error: no partitions found entering grub rescue`. Note: Everything until this point is all happening on a separate hard drive which only contains Ubuntu at the moment. I haven't remounted the Windows hard drive yet. If I reattach the Windows hard drive, it boots directly into Windows, and again no boot options for Ubuntu appear in the BIOS either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: UEFI remembers/keeps old entries. Did grub not install correctly & you are booting old entry? New install should have overwritten old "ubuntu" entry in UEFI. Does the fallback or hard drive entry boot?  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/